# extracting a selection of Textures from a Texture Atlas

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to write a method to do the above. My Texture Atlas contains more than 500 Textures. When i store my extracted Textures in a new Array and log its description the Array contains my correct named 3 Textures PLUS all of the Textures the original Atlas contained. Everyone of these is referred to " 'MissingResource.png' (128 x 128)".

My Question is: How can i ONLY store the 3 textures i want in the new Array? Here is the code:

```
-(void)createSelectedTexturesWith:(NSString*)ImageName;
{
 int bgCount = 1;

 NSMutableString *tempstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:ImageName];
 SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"textures"];
 NSMutableArray *Leveltextures = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 NSUInteger numImages = atlas.textureNames.count;

for (int i=1;i <= numImages; i++) {
    [tempstring appendFormat:@"_%02d.png",bgCount];
    NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithString:tempstring];
    SKTexture *temp = [atlas textureNamed:textureName];
    [Leveltextures addObject:temp];
    [tempstring setString:ImageName];
    bgCount++;
}

NSLog(@"Leveltextures Content: %@",[Leveltextures description]);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want. But if I do understand it correctly, why can't you just check if the textureName's prefix matches your imageName and only create the texture and add to the array in that case only ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you prototypical, that did it for me. Though the code is maybe not too elegant, here it is. Maybe it helps somebody else.

```
-(void)createSelectedTexturesWith:(NSString*)ImageName;
{
    bgCount=1;

    NSMutableString *tempstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:ImageName];
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"textures"];
    NSMutableArray *Leveltextures = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *atlasArray = [atlas textureNames];

    for (NSString *string in atlasArray) {

        if ([string hasPrefix:ImageName]){

        [tempstring appendFormat:@"%02d.png",bgCount];
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithString:tempstring];
        SKTexture *temp = [atlas textureNamed:textureName];
        [Leveltextures addObject:temp];
        [tempstring setString:ImageName];
        bgCount++;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Leveltextures Content: %@",[Leveltextures description]);

}
```